Multiple linear regression: Partial effects interpretation of parameters at/near collinearity
I am looking at the simplest example of multiple linear regression model:
\begin{equation}\label{linreg}
    Y = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \varepsilon,
\end{equation}
I am interested in the parameter estimates (estimated simultaneously) I would get when either $X_1=X_2$ (collinearity), or when $\text{cor}(X_1, X_2)$ is very high, perhaps $\text{cor}(X_1, X_2)>0.999$.
The standard interpretation of regression coefficients is in terms of partial effects: $\beta_1$ is the change in $Y$ when increasing $X_1$ by one unit, while controlling for all other variables (here only $X_2$). However, if $X_1=X_2$, $X_1$ clearly cannot explain any variance in $Y$ anymore once we controlled for $X_2$. Based on this reasoning, I would expect to get estimates $\hat\beta_1=0$ and by the same reasoning I would expect to get $\hat\beta_2=0$.
However, if I estimate the regression model (using a Bayesian model in the fully colinear case, or Bayesian/Frequentist for a near colinear case) I get beta coefficients which sum up to the sum of the true parmeters $\beta_1+\beta_2$. This also makes sense from an optimization perspective, because if $X_1=X_2$, the RHS of the above model can be rewritten as $(\beta_1+\beta_2)X_1 + \varepsilon$, which also shows why the model is not identified.
Based on the above, it seems that the partial effects interpretation of $\beta_1, \beta_2$ is inconsistent with the results I am getting in the (near) collinear case. Clearly, I am making a reasoning error and I was hoping someone could point it out to me.

The standard interpretation is correct, at least for near perfect collinearity with frequentist approaches (I am not familiar enough with Bayesian methods to comment, but I think the same would apply).
The problem is how to apportion the effects. One of the major problems caused by collinearity is that very small changes in the data can have huge effects on the parameter estimates, even changing their sign and being significant in both cases.
This arises because controlling for the other variable(s) is very hard when they are a linear combination of each other. So, different equations, with very different parameter estimates, can have the same "meaning". They will also make the same predictions. Some very crude R code:
set.seed(123)
x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = x1 + rnorm(100,0,0.01) # Almost identical
    
y = x1 + x2 + rnorm(100,0,1)
    
m1 <- lm(y~x1+x2)
coef(m1) #0.135  - 1.51x1 + 3.38x2$
    
# run again with different seed
    
x1 = rnorm(100)
x2 = x1 + rnorm(100,0,0.01) # Almost identical
    
y = x1 + x2 + rnorm(100,0,1)
    
m2 <- lm(y~x1+x2)
coef(m2) #-0.07  - 18.52x1 + 20.45x2$

Wildly different. But if you plug in different values for $x_1$ and $x_2$ you will get very similar predictions; if you make plots, they will look similar. And both estimates are controlling for the other variable.

Because of this it is not appropriate to portion effects.  Don’t separate inseparable quantities.  Use chunk tests to get combined effects of the collinear variables.  Chunk (multiple d.f.) tests perform brilliantly even with a correlation of 0.999.

(+1) I also provide a Bayesian example from McElreath's text which showcase that you get similar problems in that world too, since you mentioned that in your answer.

Thanks for your answer. I am aware of this. My question was not which parameter estimates I get and whether they are stable. Instead, I am trying to understand how  the fact that the effect is "fully" apportioned to the two parameters is consistent with the partial effects interpretation of the parameters.

The effect is not "fully apportioned" when there is collinearity any more than it is fully apportioned when there is no collinearity.  What happens is that the effect that is in the model is apportioned in very unstable ways.

In my example, R^2 = 0.76, but it is easy to make it larger or smaller.,just change the amount of variance in the noise variable in the equation starting "y="

Thanks. Then my question is actually independent of colinearity and I am interested in how to resolve the contradiction I lay out in the initial question for any cor(X1,X2). Clearly, I made some error in reasoning when starting out with the partial effects interpretation and arriving at the conclusion that the betas are zero. I would like to understand what precisely this error is.

Without a high correlation, your line of reasoning just disappears. There would be no reason to expect betas of 0.

Okay, then let's focus on the colinear case.

As far as I can tell, the colinear case has been resolved.

I guess you are not able to help me on this one. I feel like I phrased my problem of understanding quite clearly both in the original question and in the comment above. Maybe some other people are able to help! Thanks again for your efforts.

Collinearity is going to be a problem in any paradigm when it is this extreme. Peter has shown the case in a frequentist model, and here I show that the same applies to a Bayesian model, which you seem to be interested in based off the post. A useful example is from McElreath's "collinear legs" in Statistical Rethinking (around p.163). Here he simulates what would happen if you tried to predict one's height using one's left leg length as a predictor and one's right leg length as the other (using "leg proportion" as a sort of latent variable effecting both). Below is his code with some minor changes and notes added by me, which simulates the data and fits it to the quap() function for fitting Bayesian regressions:
#### Setup Simulation ####
library(rethinking)
N <- 100 # number of individuals
set.seed(909) # set random seed for reproducibility
height <- rnorm(N,10,2) # sim total height of each 
leg_prop <- runif(N,0.4,0.5) # leg as proportion of height
leg_left <- leg_prop*height + rnorm(N,0,0.02) # left leg as proportion + error 
leg_right <- leg_prop*height + rnorm(N,0,0.02) # right leg as proportion + error

#### Merge Data ####
d <- data.frame(height,leg_left,leg_right) # combine data
head(d)

#### Fit Model ####
m6.1 <- quap(
  alist(
    height ~ dnorm( mu , sigma ) , # models distribution of mean and variance
    mu <- a + bl*leg_left + br*leg_right , # models conditional mean
    a ~ dnorm( 10 , 100 ) , # normally distributed intercept coefs
    bl ~ dnorm( 2 , 10 ) , # normally distributed slope 1 coef
    br ~ dnorm( 2 , 10 ) , # normally distributed slope 2 coef
    sigma ~ dexp( 1 ) # models exponential distr. variance 
    ) ,
  data=d 
  ) # fit model, will sometimes fail because of collinearity issue

When fitting such a model, you see an explosion in the range of possible values for the slope terms:
#### Check Model ####
est <- precis(m6.1) # estimates
est # summarizes model
plot(est) # plot estimates 


The extremely wide interval for both slopes should be an indicator that the model is very poor at providing unique estimates for each leg. If we reason through this, it really isn't necessary to include both in the model, so it would be better to just use one leg's measurements or find a way to transform this variable (perhaps using a combined sum of the two). So in a case like this, as always with collinear terms, it is better to find a better route than to simply fit the model as is.

Re "model is very poor:" that is likely to be misinterpreted.  The model can be excellent in the sense of predicting heights accurately and precisely.  It can be considered "poor" only insofar as it cannot offer precise estimates of the separate contributions from the legs.

That is a fair distinction and I have amended the answer to reflect that @whuber.

Thank you. I am a big fan of this book and have read the chapter you are citing recently. However, my question is not about which parameter estimates I get or how stable/identified they are. Instead, I am trying to understand how the fact that the effect is "fully" apportioned (in the leg example: I get always between sums close to 2) to the two parameters is consistent with the partial effects interpretation of the parameters.

I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking why, when the parameters average to 2 and 0 (making their sum contribution around 2), this is in line with how partial effects work? This is still what we should expect with partial effects given the model has now downgraded the influence of one association over the other, but still weights their joint contribution based off this influence. If that doesn't make sense, perhaps you could reword your question.

Thanks again. One could read the partial effects interpretation such that one arrives at the conclusion that both betas are equal to zero in case of colinearity. A similar way to arrive a this (incorrect) conclusion is to look at the frequent Venn diagram representation of this matter, in which the partial effects interpration is explained by saying that the betas only represent the unique variance in Y explained by X1, and not the one that is also shared by X2. So my question is not what the parameter estimates are, but how to resolve the seeming contradiction I laid out in my question.

$\beta_1$ does represent the expected change in $Y$ given a one unit increase in $X_1$.
If, in reality, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are functionally equivalent, then any combination, $(\beta_1^*,\beta_2^*)$, such that $\beta_1^*+\beta_2^*=\beta_1+\beta_2$ is equally valid, we will just never observe what happens when $X_2$ is held constant and $X_1$ is modulated.
On the other hand, if it is merely a limitation of our data that $X_1= X_2$, then it should be clear that we have no information about the partial effect of $X_1$ or $X_2$, we really only have information about $\beta_1+\beta_2$.
